# How to turn off provider version and package checking during the development of a custom terraform provider?

Tags: terraform

I am writing a custom Terraform provider. Though development overrides is configured, terraform init still tries to query the provider packages.  My questions are :

1-Is there any way to skip that, particularly during the development ?
2-Do I need to place my provider in a web server ?
3-Does terraform init try to find a provider in hashicorp by default ? How can I disable it or update the default repository other than hashicorp when my provider is only used in my company only ?

Error from terraform init

Error: Failed to query available provider packages
Could not retrieve the list of available versins for provider test1.abc.com/local/webvm: no available releases match the given constraints 0.0.1

Error: Failed to query available provider packages  #
Could not retrieve the list of available versions of provider hashicorp/webvm: no available releases match the given constraints

development overrides has been set, but it seems to have no effect.

```
provider_installation {
   dev_overrides {
       "abc.com/local/webvm" = "C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Roaming/terraform.d/plugins/abc.com/local/webvm/0.0.1/windows_amd64"
   }
}
```

Related terraform definition

```
terraform {
   required_providers {
     test_provider1 = {
         source = "abc.com/local/webvm"
         version = "0.0.1"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any more information if you run `terraform init` with `TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform init`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dev_overrides` setting tells subsequent Terraform commands (like `terraform apply`) to ignore what's selected in [`.terraform.lock.hcl`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files/dependency-lock) and to use the plugin package at the specified directory instead.

This setting doesn't change the behavior of `terraform init` because that command's job is (amongst other things) to select provider packages from upstream and update the dependency lock file to refer to them.

However, since `dev_overrides` makes other Terraform commands ignore certain entries in the dependency lock file, you can skip running `terraform init` as long as your test configuration only refers to providers for which you've configured dev overrides.

Skipping `terraform init` means that you won't have an updated lock file and you won't have a provider package cached under the `.terraform` directory, but neither of those things matter if you are using `dev_overrides`: `terraform apply` will just use the directory you specified, regardless of what the lock file says or whether the lock file is even present.

---

Your error message shows that something separate is going wrong which skipping `terraform init` won't help with:

```
Could not retrieve the list of available versions of provider hashicorp/webvm:
no available releases match the given constraints
```

Terraform thinks you are trying to use a provider called `hashicorp/webvm`. The most likely reason for this is that your `required_providers` block uses the local name `test_provider1` to refer to this provider, and so when Terraform sees a `resource "webvm_something"` block elsewhere in your configuration it cannot tell that you intend to use `abc.com/local/webvm` as "webvm" here.

There are two ways to address this. You should choose only one of these options:

1. Choose the local name `webvm` for your provider. It's conventional to use the same name as the prefix on all of the resource types in the provider because then Terraform can automatically match the `webvm_` prefix to the `webvm` entry in `required_providers` to infer which provider you are intending to use:

   ```
   required_providers {
     webvm = {
       source  = "abc.com/local/webvm"
       version = "0.0.1"
     }
   }
   ```
2. In your `resource` blocks using this provider, assign the provider configuration explicitly so that Terraform does not need to infer automatically based on the resource type name prefix:

   ```
   resource "webvm_something" "example" {
     provider = test_provider1

     # ...
   }
   ```

   This approach would be very unconventional. In Terraform we typically choose a different local name for a provider only in the unusual case where a single module uses two providers that have the same remote name, and therefore they cannot possibly both have the same local name.